# Page not found (404) in Django, whenever I tried adding <int:pk> in urls.py

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

What I wanted to achieve is for the product's id to be shown in the url, whenever a user clicks it. So I tried putting **`<int:pk>`** in the url, but it says,

```
Page Not Found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/book-details/
```

**homepage.html**

```
{% for book in random %}
     <a type="submit" href="{{% url 'book-details' %}}">
         <img src="{{book.cover.url}}" height="300px" width="200px">
     </a>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def book_details(request,pk):
    return render(request, 'book-details.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', homepage, name='home'),
path('fiction', fiction, name='fiction'),
path('nonfiction', nonfiction, name='nonfiction'),
path('book-details/<int:pk>/', book_details, name='book-details'),
path('search-result', search_result, name='search-result')
```

Comment: `<int:pk>` is not optional arguments for url if you want to make it optional you can use regex version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing `<int:pk>` when calling the view , make the following change in **homepage.html** : add this code

```
<a href="{% url 'book-details' book.pk %}"
```